# Error when building GCC 6.3.0 from source on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: compiling, gcc, matlab

I tried to build GCC-6.3.0 from source following the official guide. I need this version because is the one required by the Matlab compiler. I was able to install GCC 7.4 (the default version of Ubuntu 18.04), 8.2, 6.5 and 5.5, but not 6.3.
I attempted to build 6.3, and also 6.2 just for trying, unsuccessfully. I have always obtained the following error prompt

```
In file included from ../../../gcc-6.3.0/libgcc/unwind-dw2.c:401:0:
./md-unwind-support.h: In function ‘x86_64_fallback_frame_state’:
./md-unwind-support.h:65:47: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct ucontext’
       sc = (struct sigcontext *) (void *) &uc_->uc_mcontext;
                                               ^~
/home/luis/src/build-gcc63/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/luis/src/build-gcc63/./gcc/ -B/usr/local/gcc-6.3.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/gcc-6.3.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/gcc-6.3.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/local/gcc-6.3.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include    -g -O2 -O2  -g -O2 -DIN_GCC    -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-format -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition  -isystem ./include   -fpic -mlong-double-80 -DUSE_ELF_SYMVER -g -DIN_LIBGCC2 -fbuilding-libgcc -fno-stack-protector   -fpic -mlong-double-80 -DUSE_ELF_SYMVER -I. -I. -I../.././gcc -I../../../gcc-6.3.0/libgcc -I../../../gcc-6.3.0/libgcc/. -I../../../gcc-6.3.0/libgcc/../gcc -I../../../gcc-6.3.0/libgcc/../include -I../../../gcc-6.3.0/libgcc/config/libbid -DENABLE_DECIMAL_BID_FORMAT -DHAVE_CC_TLS  -DUSE_TLS -o _muldi3_s.o -MT _muldi3_s.o -MD -MP -MF _muldi3_s.dep -DSHARED -DL_muldi3 -c ../../../gcc-6.3.0/libgcc/libgcc2.c
../../../gcc-6.3.0/libgcc/shared-object.mk:14: recipe for target 'unwind-dw2.o' failed
make[3]: *** [unwind-dw2.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/luis/src/build-gcc63/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgcc'
Makefile:19428: recipe for target 'all-stage1-target-libgcc' failed
make[2]: *** [all-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/luis/src/build-gcc63'
Makefile:23320: recipe for target 'stage1-bubble' failed
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/luis/src/build-gcc63'
Makefile:921: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does someone know how to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: For future reference, please select all in the terminal window, copy the result, then come back here and click [edit] then paste the result into your question It is far easier to read text than a screenshot.

Comment: The safe choice https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1j7qE9YKTT313B5VBg3kevzCNiykGkonO .... + do this command, followed by the configure command sequence, i.e. : `export CC=gcc-5 CXX=g++-5 && [ configure command ]`

Comment: @KnudLarsen can you be more specific? I did what you say but when I run the make command I obtain the same error. Thank you.

Comment: The unwind issue is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52498431/compile-gcc6-4-0-using-gcc8-1-1 ... But whether gcc-5 or gcc-7 is used : The gcc-6.3.0 build fails. Said to be glibc (libc6) issues. ... I intend to build gcc-6.3.0 with Ubuntu 16.04 (glibc <= 2.25 should do) , and upload to "extra Ubuntu gcc" https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xVEATaYAwqvseBzYxKDzJoZ4-Hc_XOJm?usp=sharing

Comment: Seems the gcc-6.3.0 fails Debian/Ubuntu current glibc´s. Hence gcc 6.4. The 2018 "Redhat CentOS 7" build of 6.3.0 was repacked to `gcc63-c++-6.3.0-1_amd64.deb` https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xVEATaYAwqvseBzYxKDzJoZ4-Hc_XOJm?usp=sharing ..... Provides `{gcc63, g++63}`.